# Proof that length of a finite cover for a real interval $[a,b]$ is greater than $b-a$ whenever $b>a$

Tags: integration, analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

[image]

In the above proof, i could not understand the inequality in the bottom part. Could anyone show me explicitly why it is true? (I understand about the sum be equal to b). 
Also do anyone agree that there is a mistake in the thir line of the proof? each $v(U_i)$ is the sum o  certain $t_j-t_{j-k}$ where $k>1 $ or equal one

Comment: The source of the picture is an online book of the spivak's book called Calculus on Manifolds

Comment: Each $U_i$ contains a point in some $[t_k, t_{k+1}]$.  There are no endpoints for and $U_j$ between $t_k$ and $t_{k+1}$.  So one of the end points of $U_i$ is $\le t_k$ and the other is $\ge t_{k+1}$.  So $vU_i \ge t_{k+1}- t_k$.  So $\sum vU_i \ge \sum (t_{k+1} - t_k)  = b-a$.

Comment: i agree with you @fleablood, but i am problem to see why $ \sum v U_i$ that you used in inequality contains each $U_i$, did you get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intuition of this proof is very simple, and you should be able to understand it from the given text. For a more "formal" approach set
$$\epsilon_{ij}:=\left\{\eqalign{1\qquad&\bigl(\>[t_{j-1},t_j]\subset U_i\bigr)\>,\cr 0\qquad &({\rm otherwise})\ .\cr}\right.$$
As the $U_i$ form a cover of $[a,b]$ one has $\sum_i\epsilon_{ij}\geq1$ for all $j$. On the other hand $$\nu(U_i)=\sum_j\epsilon_{ij}(t_j-t_{j-1})\ .$$ It follows that
$$\sum_i \nu(U_i)=\sum_{i,j}\epsilon_{ij}(t_j-t_{j-1})\geq \sum_j(t_j-t_{j-1})=b-a\ .$$

Comment: I agre with you the intuition is very simple, in fact i did myself two other proofs, but really wanted to understand the argument and learning something with. But your approach is very understable and avoids each one of my problems, thank you very much!